# I am trying to hit an endpoint in salesforce that will return all account and their IDS

Tags: integration

I am setting up an integration and need to pull back all accounts and their account ID's, i have not found an endpoint that i can do this with. I am getting the token first but cannot seem to hit an endpoint that will return all accounts along with their account ID's. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce isn't meant for general computing. It's a multi-tennant platform (with groups of users split into shared "pods" unless you're an extremely large customer), so allowing anyone to fetch any amount of data at any time would be bad for the other people on your pod.

You can [Execute a Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) and look at the `done` attribute to see if there are any more records that can be pulled (and then use the `nextRecordsUrl` to pull the next set of up to 2000 records). That's not going to get you all records in a single call, though it would be through a single endpoint, and could be excruciatingly slow depending on how many records you need to pull.

The general approach that I see many integrations taking (both as part of Salesforce and in the larger programming space) is to:

- Do an initial data load
- Make small, *incremental*, calls thereafter to keep data updated

Getting all of the records for the initial load is something that would be better handled by a tool like the [Salesforce-provided Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/data-loader).

Getting incremental updates is something best handled by the source/owner of the data (which sounds like it'd be Salesforce in your case). Push rather than pull. This could be handled by Salesforce making a callout to your system (rather than the other way around), or by [subscribing to Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe.htm).